# (C++) SystemParametersInfo with SPI_SetMouse does not seem to change cursor speed

Tags: c++, msdn

I've basically copied the following code straight from the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

int main()
{
   BOOL fResult;
   int aMouseInfo[3];       // array for mouse information

   // Get the current mouse speed. 

   fResult = SystemParametersInfo(
      SPI_GETMOUSE,   // get mouse information 
      0,              // not used 
      &aMouseInfo,    // holds mouse information
      0);             // not used 

   // Double it. 

   if( fResult )
   {
      aMouseInfo[2] =  1; // 2 * aMouseInfo[2]; 
      // 1 should be a very noticeable change: slowing the cursor way down
      // Change the mouse speed to the new value. 

      SystemParametersInfo(
         SPI_SETMOUSE,      // set mouse information
         0,                 // not used 
         aMouseInfo,        // mouse information 
         SPIF_SENDCHANGE);  // update win.ini 
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Yet when I run it, nothing seems to happen. The mouse speed should change, but it doesn't.

Windows Vista Home x32 (ouch)
Dev-C++ Portable

Comment: When I tested this, I output the value of `aMouseInfo [2]` every time while doubling it (your code says "= 1" instead of "*= 2"). Each time it ran, I saw the number double, which meant it was being saved throughout runs, but setting it both low and high didn't physically change the mouse speed for me.

Comment: That's one thing that confuses me: there aren't any errors, and the member of the struct stays changed, but the actual mouse speed is unaffected. Meanwhile, calling SystemParametersInfo from AutoHotkey works just fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here , aMouseInfo[2] refers to **Enhance Mouse Precision field**.
if aMouseInfo[2] is set to TRUE ( or assigned any no. other than 0 ), then **Enhance Mouse Precision field** is SET and if FALSE ( or assigned 0 ) then **Enhance Mouse Precision field** is UNSET .

For getting and setting the Mousespeed you can use SPI_GETMOUSESPEED and SPI_SETMOUSESPEED resp.

To use SPI_GETMOUSESPEED and SPI_SETMOUSESPEED , please refer to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16813653/2153564) .