# Mouse speed not changing by using SPI_SETMOUSESPEED

Tags: c++, winapi, mouse, msdn

Why mouse speed is not changing after execution of the following program ?

Is it due to **SPI_SETMOUSESPEED** or due to unable to change the **winini** file by **SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE** , **SPIF_SENDCHANGE** and **SPIF_SENDCHANGE** parameters ?

Compiler : **g++** , OS : **Windows 8** .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include<winuser.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

using namespace std ;

int main()
{
    int i = 0 , *MouseSpeed = &i ;

    bool x ;

//  Retrieving the mouse speed . 

    x = SystemParametersInfo( SPI_GETMOUSESPEED , 0 , MouseSpeed , 0 ) ;

    cout<<"\n\nPrevious Mouse Speed was : " << *MouseSpeed ;

    cout<<"\n\nSystemParametersInfo return status for SPI_GETMOUSESPEED : " << x ;

    if( x )
    {
        i = 20 ;

        MouseSpeed = &i ;

//  Changing the mouse speed .

        SystemParametersInfo( SPI_SETMOUSESPEED ,
                              0 ,
                              MouseSpeed ,
                              SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE ||
                              SPIF_SENDCHANGE ||
                              SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE ) ;

        cout<<"\n\nCurrent Mouse Speed is : " << *MouseSpeed ;

        cout<<"\n\nSystemParametersInfo return status for SPI_SETMOUSESPEED : " << x << "\n\n" ;
    }

    if( !x )        
        cout<< "Error Status : " << GetLastError() << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not alone, and it looks like someone likes my icon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848423/c-systemparametersinfo-with-spi-setmouse-does-not-seem-to-change-cursor-spee?rq=1

Comment: What does SystemParametersInfo return (true or false) ? If it returns false, check the error number returned by GetLastError(), this may give you a clue.

Comment: I tried , but didn't worked.

Comment: @chris : Your SPI_SETMOUSE is working fine see... http://stackoverflow.com/a/16814574/2153564

Comment: @birajbora, Huh. It was over a year ago and all I remember was trying something, seeing the numbers change, but not seeing the speed change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing the wrong value as `pvParam` for `SPI_SETMOUSESPEED`.   From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Sets the current mouse speed. The **pvParam parameter is an integer**
>   between 1 (slowest) and 20 (fastest). A value of 10 is the default.
>   This value is typically set using the mouse control panel application.

Compare that to the documentation for `SPI_GETMOUSESPEED`

> Retrieves the current mouse speed. The mouse speed determines how far
>   the pointer will move based on the distance the mouse moves. The
>   **pvParam parameter must point to an integer** that receives a value which ranges between 1 (slowest) and 20 (fastest). A value of 10 is
>   the default. The value can be set by an end-user using the mouse
>   control panel application or by an application using
>   SPI_SETMOUSESPEED.

So for `SPI_GETMOUSESPEED` you must pass an `int*` value as `pvParam`, but for `SPI_SETMOUSESPEED` you must pass in `int` value.  You are passing an `int*` in both cases.  Your call for `SPI_SETMOUSESPED` should be:

```
SystemParametersInfo(
    SPI_SETMOUSESPEED,
    0,
    (LPVOID) newMouseSpeed,
    SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE
);
```

Comment: Don't use the `||` (LOGICAL OR) operator to combine flag bits.  Use the `|` (BITWISE OR) operator instead. `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE || SPIF_SENDCHANGE || SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE` evaluates as `true`, which is just `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE` (0x01) by itself when converted to an integer.