# JNA SystemParametersInfo to set mouse speed is returning false (not changing)

Tags: java, windows, winapi, jna

I'm using JNA to call *SystemParametersInfo* from *user32*. This is my JNA interface method:

```
boolean SystemParametersInfo(
        int uiAction,
        int uiParam,
        Pointer pvParam,
        int fWinIni
);
```

And here's how I use it:

```
User32.INSTANCE.SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSESPEED, 0,
    new IntByReference(2).getPointer(),
    SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
```

This should set the mouse speed to 2 (out of 20) but it has no effect and the method is always returning false.

These are the flag values that I use:

```
private static final int SPI_GETMOUSESPEED = 0x70;
private static final int SPI_SETMOUSESPEED = 0x0071;
private static final int SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
private static final int SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x02;
private static final int SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;
```

Comment: Could you list the flags you used? (Ex SPI_SETMOUSESPEED, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE etc).

Comment: Did you check the value of `Native.GetLastError()`?

Comment: @technomage `GetLastError` is _0_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of `SystemParametersInfo()` is a `BOOL`, aka an alias for a 4-byte `int`. So use `int` instead of `boolean` on the Java side for the return value.

That aside, the reason `SystemParametersInfo()` is failing is because you are not passing in the speed value correctly.  Read the `SPI_SETMOUSESPEED` documentation carefully:

> SPI_SETMOUSESPEED
>   0x0071
>  
>   Sets the current mouse speed. **The pvParam parameter is an integer** between 1 (slowest) and 20 (fastest). A value of 10 is the default. This value is typically set using the mouse control panel application.

Compare that to the `SPI_GETMOUSESPEED` documentation:

> SPI_GETMOUSESPEED
>   0x0070 
>   Retrieves the current mouse speed. The mouse speed determines how far the pointer will move based on the distance the mouse moves. **The pvParam parameter must point to an integer** that receives a value which ranges between 1 (slowest) and 20 (fastest). A value of 10 is the default. The value can be set by an end-user using the mouse control panel application or by an application using SPI_SETMOUSESPEED.

So, even though the `pvParam` parameter is declared as a pointer, `SPI_SETMOUSESPEED` wants the *actual integer value*, not a *pointer to an integer that holds the value*, like you are currently passing by using `IntByReference.getPointer()`.  This is confirmed in the answer to this question (though for C++, not Java):

[Mouse speed not changing by using SPI_SETMOUSESPEED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813653/)

In C/C++, the solution is like this:

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSESPEED, 0,
    (void*)2,
    SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
```

In Java, the equivalent is more like this:

```
User32.INSTANCE.SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSESPEED, 0,
    Pointer.createConstant(2),
    SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! The method still works with a `boolean` as the return type, I did not fully read the documentation. Did not know about `Pointer.createConstant` either! Thanks!

Comment: Since you've already added your own mapping for `SystemParametersInfo`, you might as well just add a new function declaration that takes an `int` as the third parameter and dispense with the artificial `Pointer` construct.

Comment: @technomage: There are operations (like `SPI_GETMOUSESPEED`) where a real pointer is expected, and some (like `SPI_SETMOUSESPEED`) were an integer are expected instead. Can you overload the `SystemParametersInfo()` declaration in Java to handle both cases? I do not know.

Comment: You can add as many unique signatures as are supported by the underlying call, thus adding some degree of type safety to an otherwise unsafe system.